# Cannot be divided by zero in SQL Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am wondering if there is a way to not use the division if the divisor = 0. In this case, i have the query working fine except when it has to be divided by 0. It should give the answer as 0 if the divisor is 0.Is it possible? This is in SQl 2005.

Thanks!

```
Select sum(cast(isnull(S.AmountSold, 0) as numeric(10,2))) As DeliveryTotal,
sum(cast(isnull(S.S_AmountCollected, 0) as numeric(10,2))) as DeliveryTotalCollected
(sum(cast(isnull(S.S_AmountCollected, 0) as numeric(10,2))) / sum(cast(isnull(S.AmountSold, 0) as numeric(10,2))) )*100 as DeliveryTotalPercentageCollected

from Info RD
```

Comment: You should be able to use a `case` function, which acts like a ternary operatory: `select column1,case column2 when 'Y' then 'abc' else 'xyz' end column2 from table1`

Comment: I missed the bit about it showing 0. I removed my answer :)

Comment: yes - sorry, should have read the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `case when`, and maybe a subquery to make things easier to read...

```
select DeliveryTotal, DeliveryTotalCollected, 
 case 
   when DeliveryTotalCollected = 0 --if divisor = 0
   then 0 --return 0
   else (DeliveryTotal / DeliveryTotalCollected) * 100 --return division * 100
 end as DeliveryTotalPercentageCollected
from
(Select 
 sum(cast(isnull(S.AmountSold, 0) as numeric(10,2))) As DeliveryTotal,
 sum(cast(isnull(S.S_AmountCollected, 0) as numeric(10,2))) as DeliveryTotalCollected
 from Info RD) as subq
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into the CASE expression:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

It will allow you to decide between the two cases

Comment: Look into CASE with a link to an off-site location is not an answer. Post an example of using it; without that, this belongs as a comment to the question instead.

Comment: @Ken White: Thanks for pointing my wrong use of StackOverflow. I'm eager to learn the proper ways, so could you point me to the specific section/articles of the documentation of what is an acceptable answers ? Thanks

Comment: @mrlucmorin - You can go here (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) and here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: [Certainly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/172661). Answers should contain enough information that they are useful on their own without any external content. While it's unlikely with an MS link, answers with most of the content off-site become meaningless if that external site is unavailable for some reason. Also, if most of the content is elsewhere, it means you have to leave SO in order to get your answer. If you want to link off-site, answer the question and then provide the link as a "see-also" reference, or just post it as a comment. :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I'll try to give more context in my answers.